# Swift 5 IOS facebook share dialog, is not showing on my app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdksharedialog

I have one week trying to show the shareDialog from facebook, but nothing works fine,
my button for login is working, my work in Android is working fine, but IOs is not working, I have install my SDK from Facebook, I put all the folders Bolt in to the proyect, but nothing seems to work for me, I already made the migration for facebookSDK https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/blob/master/MigrationGuide.md

and doesnt work to, what im doing wrong, here is my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )
        return true
    }

    func application(
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {
        return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            options: options
        )
    }
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        AppEvents.activateApp()
    }



    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

and here is the ViewController.swift:

````
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func ShareButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title : "Comparte", message:"Comparte con amigos", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let actionOne = UIAlertAction(title: "Comparte en facebook", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in

            let sharePhoto = SharePhoto()
            sharePhoto.imageURL = URL(string: "https://www.hola.com/imagenes/actualidad/20171204102954/adelanto-portada-revista-hola/0-514-626/adelanto-hola1-t.jpg")

            let content = SharePhotoContent()
            content.photos = [sharePhoto]

            self.showShareDialog(content)

        }
        alert.addAction(actionOne)

       self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let loginButton = FBLoginButton(permissions: [ .publicProfile ])
        loginButton.center = view.center

        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

     func showShareDialog<C: SharingContent>(_ content: C, mode: ShareDialog.Mode = ShareDialog.Mode.automatic) {
        let dialog = ShareDialog(fromViewController: self, content: content, delegate: self as? SharingDelegate)
            dialog.mode = mode

            dialog.show()
    }

     func sharer(_ sharer: Sharing, didCompleteWithResults results: [String: Any]) {
        print("success")

        let title = "Share Success"
        let message = "Thank You"
        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    func sharer(_ sharer: Sharing, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error")

        let title = "Share Failed"
        let message = "Something went wrong. Please try again"
        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: Sharing) {
        print("canceled")

        let title = "Share Cancelled"
        let message = "Share on Facebook was Cancelled"
        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```
````

Comment: did you find a solution please?

Comment: Did you solve it? Currently I'm facing this issue with latest version of Facebook SDK.  I did everything but didn't work. 
I'm trying to share video from my app.

Answer (score 0):

making may a question I found some of the answer, so I made it with the share dialog with link content, the problem resides in the creation of the content, I resolve the problem for links content, I´ll try with the others types of content and I show you how to make it done, mean while, here is the correct code with the correct content, and remember this is swift 5

```
let content = ShareLinkContent()

        let api = "https://developers.facebook.com"
        let endpoint = "/"
        let url = URL(string: api + endpoint)
        content.contentURL = url!

        let dialog = ShareDialog(fromViewController: self, content: content, delegate: self as? SharingDelegate)
        dialog.mode = mode
        print(dialog.canShow)
        dialog.show()
```

Comment: but this not resolve the question, cause I want to share a video, not just a link